# Duplicate Messages in Message Manager

Tags: sapui5, sap-gateway

I'm getting duplicate messages in my frontend MessageManager.  I know *why* I'm getting it (msg_code differs between outer and inner messages) but I have no idea how to fix this...  It's one simple message returning, using $batch changeset_processing.

Gateway code:

```
    CALL METHOD mo_context->get_message_container( )->add_messages_from_bapi(
      EXPORTING
         it_bapi_messages = lt_return
         iv_determine_leading_msg = /iwbep/if_message_container=>gcs_leading_msg_search_option-first ).

    RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE /iwbep/cx_mgw_tech_exception
      EXPORTING
        message_container = mo_context->get_message_container( ).
```

I've seen many websites which don't really explain how to remove this.  The SAP help just says "Messages will be duplicated if they have different codes".  I only have 1 message...

Could someone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: how many messages are you getting in $batch?

Comment: Just the one...